# Adding checkboxes to textarea in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I posted this earlier, but deleted the post due to formatting errors.  I have a seen a few similar responses but they have been given negative scores so I thought I would post one up.

I have checkboxes that pull names from an SQL list using Ajax (which are echoed as checkboxes) and I want to when they are checked be posted in the textarea below when 'Add Selected Names' is clicked on

Here is my code, it functions for all and selects the figures ok (as the alerts test them). But doesn't pass the values to the textarea.

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/B4PvJ/1/

**HTML:**

```
<form name="promoForm4" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action=cp007.php onSubmit="return validateForm();">
    <ul class=mainForm id="mainForm_1">
        <select name="nameoflist" onchange="changeFunc(this);">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Recipients</option>
            <option value="All Recipients">All Recipients</option>
            <option value="Tech_List">Tech List</option>
        </select>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkall">Check All
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="list_output" style="width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto;"></div>
            <p><a href="#" class="add_names">Add Selected Names</a>

                <p>
                    <textarea readonly rows="10" cols="100" name="name_list_box"></textarea>
                    <p class="mainForm">
                        <input id="saveForm" class="mainForm" type="submit" value="Enter Track Details" />
                        </li>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $(".add_names").click(function () {
        alert("clicked");
        var allVals = [];
        $(".cb:checked").each(function () {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert(allVals);
    });
});

function changeFunc(obj) {
    $('.checkall').prop('checked', false);
    $("#list_output").empty();
    var selectedValue = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    var url = "getnames.php?list_name=" + selectedValue;
    $.get(url, function (data, status) {
        var recep_list = data.split("^");
        var r_len = recep_list.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < r_len; i++) {
            recep = recep_list[i].split("~");
            $('#list_output').append('<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="' + recep[1] + '" /> ' + recep[0] + '<br>');
        }
    });
}
$(".add_names").click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
    var allVals = [];
    $(".cb").each(function () {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
        alert("somethingchecked");
    });
    var stringvals = allVals.join(" ");
    $("#name_list_box").val($("#name_list_box").val() + stringvals);
    alert(allVals);
});
$(".checkall").click(function () {
    $('#list_output .cb').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Many thanks

CP

Comment: Java? It's **JavaScript** what you use in your question.

Comment: can you simplify your question a little bit. Like what is not working!!!

Comment: Apologies, how can i pass the values of checkboxes that are selected to the textarea.... ?